# Adapting query to use CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, query-performance

I'm looking for to use CTE in my query because I get kind of same select but I've never used CTE before, can someone help me?

I need that firstTable can be used in the others selects

```
SELECT firstTable.id as id,
   secondTable.holder as holder
FROM (
select tb3.id as id
from table1 tb1
inner join table2 tb2 on tb1.tb2_id = tb2.id
inner join table3 tb3 on tb2.tb3_id = tb3.id and tb3.id
inner join table4 tb4 on tb4.id = tb3.tb4_id and tb4.id = 1998
group by tb3.id) as firstTable
JOIN (
select id_holder,
       sum(temporaryTable.holder) as holder
from (
    select cast(tb4.helper as integer) as helper,
           count(distinct tb4.id) as holder,
           tb3.id as id_holder
    from table1 tb1
    inner join table2 tb2 on tb1.tb2_id = tb2.id
    inner join table3 tb3 on tb2.tb3_id = tb3.id and tb3.id
    inner join table4 tb4 on tb4.id = tb3.tb4_id and tb4.id = 1998
    group by tb3.id, tb4.helper
) as temporaryTable
where temporaryTable.helper between 7 and 8
group by id_holder) as secondTable
ON firstTable.id = temporaryTable.id_holder
```

Here is my trying query:

```
WITH temporary_table AS
  ( SELECT id,
           cast(resp.valor AS integer) AS holder,
           count(val) AS sumId
   FROM table1 tb1
   INNER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb1.tb2_id = tb2.id
   INNER JOIN table3 tb3 ON tb2.tb3_id = tb3.id
   AND tb3.id
   INNER JOIN table4 tb4 ON tb4.id = tb3.tb4_id
   AND tb4.id = 1998
   GROUP BY tb3.id )
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(sumId)
   WHERE holder = -10) AS p1,

  (SELECT SUM(sumId)
   WHERE holder = 78) AS p2,

  (SELECT SUM(sumId)
   WHERE holder = 1997) AS p3,
       id
FROM temporary_table
GROUP BY id,
         holder;
```

Comment: You can refer to `CTE` doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Comment: I'm but I can't put my "where" clause at the end :/ It's no working

Comment: It would be better if you post your `no working` trying here. We're glad to help you fix that rather than just write all this cte for you

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I'll edit the question

Comment: Your `CTE` query seem not equal to your first query. And your `SELECT (select SUM(sumId) where holder = -10) as p1,` will not work even if you didn't use `CTE`. You should change it to a `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN  holder = -10 THEN sumId END) AS p1,` and not group by holder

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I got it... It will also work if I change "=" for "between" for example?

Comment: If you want to get sum for holder between two values, then yes. But it seems that your problem is now go far from your original question. If you have more to ask, please explain it all in your Post. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straightforward to use CTEs for each sub-query:

```
WITH firstTable AS (
    select tb3.id as id
    from table1 tb1
        inner join table2 tb2 on tb1.tb2_id = tb2.id
        inner join table3 tb3 on tb2.tb3_id = tb3.id and tb3.id
        inner join table4 tb4 on tb4.id = tb3.tb4_id and tb4.id = 1998
    group by tb3.id
), temporaryTable AS (
    select cast(tb4.helper as integer) as helper,
           count(distinct tb4.id) as holder,
           tb3.id as id_holder
    from table1 tb1
        inner join table2 tb2 on tb1.tb2_id = tb2.id
        inner join table3 tb3 on tb2.tb3_id = tb3.id and tb3.id
        inner join table4 tb4 on tb4.id = tb3.tb4_id and tb4.id = 1998
    group by tb3.id, tb4.helper
), secondTable AS (
select id_holder,
       sum(temporaryTable.holder) as holder
from temporaryTable
where temporaryTable.helper between 7 and 8
group by id_holder
)
    SELECT firstTable.id as id,
       secondTable.holder as holder
    FROM firstTable
        JOIN secondTable
            ON firstTable.id = temporaryTable.id_holder;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's more performatic than the other one right?

Comment: CTEs can help with making queries more readable, but it is not going to speed up the queries. If anything, I have seen in my experience like other answer suggests that indexes are not always leveraged properly when you might expect them to. For performance improvements, consider if additional indexes or temp tables would be useful.

Comment: @t9217: sometimes CTEs make things faster, sometimes they make things slower and sometimes they don't have any impact on performance. The only way to find out is to run `explain (analyze)` for each version and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select tb3.id as id,
       count(distinct CASE WHEN tb4.helper between 7 and 8 THEN tb4.id END) as holder,
from table1 tb1
inner join table2 tb2 on tb1.tb2_id = tb2.id
inner join table3 tb3 on tb2.tb3_id = tb3.id and tb3.id
inner join table4 tb4 on tb4.id = tb3.tb4_id and tb4.id = 1998
group by tb3.id
```

Answer (score -1):

I will just provide a tangent on the question itself.

I would strongly advice you to **NOT use CTEs** at all.  If you want to have an elegant query that looks nice, I believe it would be better that just format your queries properly.
http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

CTEs have an inherent problem of being slow as somehow the index are not properly triggering most of the time.  I have been doing SQL as a profession for so many years i have encountered lots of performance issues in CTEs.  To make CTEs faster is difficult and I argue not worth the effort.  They make debugging and testing queries a pain too especially when there are lots of tables in the CTE.  It is simply hard to compartmentalize the sub-queries especially testing if the assumption of a previous sub-query is still valid.

You can also check out below at least 500+ questions in stackoverflow regarding CTE being slow:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=slow+cte

My advice is put the data in a temp table instead.  You can also remove duplicate code by just reusing the temp table.   As an added bonus for better performance, you can have indexes in the temp tables.  You cannot create on the fly indexes in CTEs.  The only reason why to use a CTE in my opinion is for recursive CTEs.  https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/